# my cron job was running properly but suddenly it stopped executing and I get entry in cron log file as (CRON) Bad Minute. Please help me out

Tags: cron

Here's my cron job

00 02 * * * /usr/bin/wget -q
http://alaska/samuel/batch/JOB_daily_attendance.php

Here's log entry in cron log file

crond[26113]: (CRON) bad minute (/var/spool/cron/roots)

Answer (score 0):

The cron looks fine to me. Try this command on your crontab file that contains the command to show any unwanted characters:

cat -v